# how to launch asp.net website on TIVO device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tivo

i have searched a lot over it, but i have not received information for running  hosted asp.net website on Tivo
When i m going through

1. Apps and  Games
2. Add An App

   i m trying to provide my computer IP address and it throws server error ,give me some suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I also had a bad experience with TiVo few days ago.So that  I am giving you link of documentation of how to launch opera app on TiVo box, It may help you

[Tivo Opera testing guide link][1]

1. https://dev.opera.com/tv/testing-your-app-inside-opera-tv-store/